# Assassin's creed 2 confrontation between Ezio and Rodrigo

Tags: assassins-creed-2

Near the end in Assassin's creed 2 we see Ezio stabbing Rodrigo Borgia then after a little fight Rodrigo stabs Ezio.

Neither seem to be affected by the stabs. Is there any canon explanation of this within the game's story?

Comment: Videogame logic.

Comment: Could have been used to it. I can't imagine getting stabbed/stabbed back isn't something that an assassin finds rare.

Comment: Would the down-voter please explain why to improve the question?

Comment: It's a plot hole, or rather a classic example of being liberal with the rules for the sake of narrative convenience. Any stab kills anyone, unless the story says so.

Comment: If I remember well, after Ezio has been stabbed there is another little fight, during which Ezio has less life. My memory could be failing me there.

And uh... sometimes, Ezio jumps from 30-meter buildings, and seems not to be affected. Is there canon explanation of this within the game's story ? Same question for healing, etc. :D